# useContext giving me undefined value on different components after setting that value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am creating a context for a log in, so after creating the context I wrap all my routes with that context.provider and send the initial value to each child, which in my case is a useState:

```
<userContext.Provider value={{loggedUser, setLoggedUser}}>
```

I have a component LogInMenu.jsx that basically sets the loggedUser (loggedUser has a username/password structure) to a valid user. I consume the context in LogInMenu.jsx like this:

```
const { loggedUser, setLoggedUser } = useContext(userContext)
```

After succesfully console logging the loggedUser value in LogInMenu.jsx (just to make sure it was correct) I go to my other component called Dashboard.jsx and consume the context there the same way as I consumed it in LogInMenu.jsx, but this time, If I console log the loggedUser it gives me undefined value.

Note: I have imported useContext hook in each of the components that use it like this:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
```

and the context I created like this:

```
import { userContext } from './App';
```

If you need more code to understand the issue I can provide it.

Comment: Just provide the code link like codesandbox, will show more clearly.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-newton-rt0jfq

Answer (score 0):

I was going thru the code sandbox example, few points to consider
try moving the code inside the submit event handler

```
const submitData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Ideally use post instead of get
    // pass user id and password to Api
    // password should never be stored in plain text in backend
    // depending on the backend store it as hash and authenticate 
    // user Id/name and password in the backend
    const loginResponse =  await axios.get(`http://localhost:8002/users/${user}`)
    if (loginResponse.isSuccess) {
       setLoggedUser(loginResponse.userInfo)
    }

 };
```

You can get a good idea about React with their [new documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context).

Cheers